# Beginner Python: Panda Groupby function (Aggregating columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to use the panda groupby/aggregate function to show the total leave hours (combination of VacationHours & SickLeaveHours) grouped by ManagerID & JobTitle.  I am unsure how to show one total column that aggregates VacationHours+SickLeaveHours.

```
excel = pd.read_excel('Employees.xls','Sheet0',index_col=None,na_values=['NA'])
excel.groupby(['ManagerID','JobTitle']).agg(({'VacationHours': np.sum,'SickLeaveHours': 
np.sum}))
```

[image: Below is the current output that shows the correct grouping but a column for vacationHours & SickLeaveHours where I want the output to be one total column]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the total

```
out = excel.groupby(['ManagerID','JobTitle']).agg(({'VacationHours':np.sum,
                                                    'SickLeaveHours':np.sum}))
out['total'] = out.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `transform`

```
new_df = (df.assign(total=df[['VacationHours', 'SickLeaveHours']].sum(axis=1))
            .assign(lambda df: df.groupby(['ManagerID','JobTitle'])['total'].transform('sum'))
         )
```